# Linking a library twice and size of executable

Tags: c++, dependencies, static-libraries

When compiling a program with static libraries, it was suggested to me from many sources (including SO community) to include the library twice.

As in:

```
gcc main.c -lslA -lslB -lslC -lslA -lslB -o final
```

1. Does this result in a bigger executable (.i.e. is the linker smart enough to avoid double inclusion?).
2. Is this (multiple inclusion) the proper solution or a workaround (.i.e. will there always exist a more proper, even if harder way to handle it)

Comment: No, it will not make the executable bigger.

Comment: @n.m. I did not expect that. Which brings me to the question: why doesn't the linker do that automatically .i.e. look for `undefined references` in the other linked libraries .i.e. why does ordering matter.

Comment: If you need it multiple times on the linker line, then this sounds more like messed up dependencies

Comment: The linker looks for dependencies linearly. If you have `-lA -lB`, the linker goes like this: process A, forget it for good, process B. If B depends on A, and the relevant symbols were not already pulled, the link will fail. Including a library multiple times is a way to cope with circular dependencies. `--start/end-group` is another (GNU-specific) way. It's better to not have any in the first place though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only reason to include the library multiple times is, for example, if `slA` requires a symbol resolved by `slB` but `slB` requires a symbol required by `slA`. The linker does a single pass to resolve symbols, but repeating your library causes, in effect, a second pass on that library. It won't change the size of your output, but it's not necessary either:

Instead of presenting your libraries multiple times, you can tell the gcc linker to group certain libraries together -- letting it do what it needs to resolve the symbols within that group. For example:

`gcc main.c -Wl,--start-group -lslA -lslB -lslC -Wl,--end-group -o final`